# Why does mod-rewrite rule A work but not B?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, rule

This works, as in redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^.*$ system/snapshot.php?project=%1
```

...but this doesn't (note removal of `^` and `$` anchors):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=([^&]+)
RewriteRule .* system/snapshot.php?project=%1
```

Can anyone explain why, seemingly, I *must* anchor to the start and end of the path part of the URL?

Since the query string is what's important for this rule, not the path, I figured I could just say "run this rule regardless of what the path contains", hence `.*`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try changing `.*` to `(.*)`?

Comment: How do you know 2nd rule isn't working?

Comment: @anubhava - like I said, it doesn't redirect.

Comment: Rule is only (internally) rewriting there is no redirection here.

Comment: I realise that, but it does not redirect - silently or otherwise - to the desired page. As I said in my question, if I anchor, it *does*.

Comment: Try to use the only `^` if that work?

Comment: Are these your only rewrite rules? In local testing, I got the same behavior with or without the anchoring.